# Poker Equity Calulator

Tags: monte-carlo, games

I am writing a tool that calculates the chance of winning a poker hand.

Without going into the rules each player has 2 hole cards and there are 5 shared cards on the board.  From 2 cards in the hand plus the 5 on the board you make the  best 5 card hand and best hand wins.

For two known hands I can just iterate through all the possible boards (combinations) and calculate the chance of winning.

Against an unknown hand there are too many combinations to run them all in a reasonable period of time.

Hand is not order dependent. Only have to consider the combinations.  I have loops that delivers the combinations.

Is this a reasonable / proper approach?
Is there a better approach?

- remove the two known cards from the deck
- shuffle the remaining 50 cards
  [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)
- take the first 5 cards for the board (shared)
- take the next two cards for the unknown hand
- determine the winner
- discards the first card
- rotate first card from unknown hand to board
- unknown hand gets next combination card from shuffle
- determine winner
- back to discard

Can get though about 1/4 of the combination in 10 seconds.  Most users would rather have a good answer in 10 seconds than wait a minute.

Loop is good as I used it on $\binom{52}{5}$ to brute force the chances of hands and matches the answer on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability) exactly.

The zero based loop for all the $\binom{50}{7}$ combinations
It creates the correct number of combinations

```
for(int i = 49; i >= 6; i--)
   for(int j = i-1; j >= 5; j--) 
      for(int k = j-1; k >= 4; k--)
          for(int m = k-1; , >= 3; m--)  
             for(int n = m-1; n >= 2; n--) 
                for(int p = n-1; p >= 1; p--) 
                   for(int q = p-1; q >= 0; q--)
```

Not sure if this is Monte Carlo but I still felt like it is was proper tag.
But would like to know if it is a valid Monte Carlo.

Comment: It is not clear to me how does the loops-code relate to your question? There is no shuffle step. Monte Carlo means using some kind of randomization.

Comment: A shuffle is not randomization?   It is the loop I would use for getting the cards.

Comment: It is, it just was not clear for me how does the code relate to the question...